# Защита от редактивания html кода пользователем

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Допустим есть форма, которая меняет данные в таблице БД. Передача id элемента в обработик происходит через ссылку, т.е.

`<form action="/administrator/element_edit/ID ЭЛЕМЕНТА" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">`

Таким образом пользователь может через стандартные инструменты разработчика в браузере поменять id элемента и изменить не тот элемент.
Как это предотвращать? В вэб-разработке новичок, камнями не бросайте

Comment: никак. более того, для отправки запроса с разными ID элемента пользователю даже не нужно html менять

Comment: Если пользователь __имеет право__ (авторизован, принадлежит нужной группе) изменять элемент, то он сам дурак, что полез в разметку и поменял какие-то данные на другие. Однако, если у пользователя __нет прав__, а он поменял данные и успешно обновил, то дурак - разработчик, что не проверил вышеуказанное - авторизацию, права и все такое.

Comment: @u_mulder нет, с правами всё окей, и в принципе пользователи подразумеваются не такие смышленые)) но как-то всё равно корёжит тот факт, что есть такая возможность, как будто делаешь что-то неправильно

Comment: Если пользователь имеет право поменять элемент с любым ID, то какая разница как именно он это сделает: "рекомендованным способом" или "хакерским"? А если пользователь имеет право менять элементы только с конкретным ID, то тут разработчик должен принять меры по недопущению взлома.

Comment: Тебя должен корежить тот факт, что ты не понимаешь, как работает клиент-серверное приложение. И сервер вообще не имеет никакого влияния на то, что происходит на клиенте.

Answer (score -1):

> Передача id элемента в обработик происходит через ссылку, т.е.
>
> `<form action="/administrator/element_edit/ID ЭЛЕМЕНТА" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">`
>
> Таким образом пользователь может через стандартные инструменты
> разработчика в браузере поменять id элемента и изменить не тот
> элемент. Как это предотвращать?

Во первых стоит понять, что в `action` формы ID элементов не пишут. Их **передают** в обработчик **через поля** формы. А обработчик должен быть один на все элементы одного типа.

Во вторых уже в обработчике проверяется что нужно. Кроме ID элемента это могут быть различные данные. Например рефферер, пользователь, или даже [nonce](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce), если нужно.

Comment: все нормально он передает, и про nonce с реферером ты ерунды напел. единственное что здесь правильно, это " уже в обработчике проверяется что нужно"

Comment: Удаляторы, блин.. Хорошо, я повторю по другому. Ерунду напел ты. Это только полный профан будет делать по отдельному обработчику на каждую **типовую** форму и не проверять при этом входные данные.